# How to delete individual records from a report ?

Tags: reporting, custom-object

I have a report that contains all the members for our next event but I did the report before I've put the page up live for registering so now I have some test cases.> is there any way of removing it ? 

 
One thing I noticed is that there is a conference data object in the system that the previous guy created But I have no access to get the information from it's an object that stores information and it isn't on tabs. Would SOQL query be sufficient enough to getting rid of those ?

[image]
[image]

If anyone willing needs any more information or screens please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tab Setup - Tabs and connect it to a custom object. That way you will have access to all the records. Do it manually for small amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way is to have the report include the record id then use data loader to delete those records. It will just mean exporting the report to .csv then uploading with dataloader to delete them.

The csv file can be edited and only the records to delete left in it, then with Data Loader there is an option to 'Delete' records when you connect. If you then upload the edited file that only contains the records to delete it will move all of them into the Recycle bin and only leave the records you want in the event.

This will leave any other records that are not in the file to Delete untouched.

To get the Data Loader desktop tool go to Setup-->Administer-->Data Management-->Data Loader then download and install the Data Loader tool on your desktop. This supports both Windows and Mac. When the Data Loader starts up the following options are available.
[image: SF Data Loader]

Comment: Do i download the csv with all the records, delete them then upload them without the unwanted records ? wouldnt the unwanted records stay the same in the object ?

Comment: @Greg - I've edited my answer to make it clearer. Only the unwanted records need to be in the file used with Data Loader as it has a delete mode.

Comment: Yes but won't it delete the records and replace them with the ones inside of the CSV file ?

Comment: No, because Data Loader has 3 modes - Insert (create new), Upsert (Create new and update existing) and Delete (remove specified existing records). By using Delete mode the selected records (ones that you wish to remove) will be deleted and the other records left untouched.

Comment: Right so on my report Do i just include the ID of the specific records ?

Comment: @Greg that is correct.

Comment: I can only see "Update" Instead of delete. I did everything you said and the information is still on salesforce and on the report

Comment: @Greg is that using the Data Import Wizard accessed from the Setup page or the Data Loader run from the desktop?